# Invoke ViewComponent using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core

I have a web page with a couple of view components, when I click on these components I open a simple editor for it, see image below. If I edit the text and hit enter, I would like to rerender the view component and not the hole page. Is it possible to invoke a view component using javascript to get this behaviour?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible today but you could build a standard proxy for viewcomponents if you'd like though (similarly you could build a proxy to partial views). e.g. you a catchall attribute route on an action.

Answer (score 6):

With updates, you should now be able to do this with asp.net core.  You can return a ViewComponent from an IActionResult, then just call it with jQuery:

```
[Route("text-editor")]
public IActionResult TextEditor()
{
    return ViewComponent("TextEditorViewComponent");
}
```

Then this can be called from your View with something as simple as this:

```
function showTextEditor() {
    // Find the div to put it in
    var container = $("#text-editor-container");
    $.get("text-editor", function (data) { container.html(data); });
 }
```

If you need to pass parameters to the ViewComponent you can do so in the IActionResult (maybe they trickle through from the View to there, to the view component, etc).